# How to install Kvantum

Tags: kde, 17.04, plasma

I'm running Kubuntu 17.04 and want to install Kvantum, but apparently there is no package. How do I do that? Maybe a PPA, maybe download a .deb file?

Comment: See [Kvantum's Github repo](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/releases). They provide a downloadable .deb

Answer (score 4):

When I installed the Adapta-KDE theme, Kvantum manager installed automatically:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:papirus/papirus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends adapta-kde
```

Hope that it helps! :-)

Then, run the following command, logout and login.

```
echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: how updated is the Kvantum version from the papirus repo compared to the source on github?

Answer (score 2):

For Debian / Ubuntu / Linux Mint, there are deb binaries available to download but for a quite old version (Kvantum 0.10.5, released back in October, 2017).

To install the latest Kvantum in Debian, Ubuntu or Linux Mint, you can compile it from source. To do this, follow the steps below.

## Install the build dependencies

```
sudo apt install g++ cmake libx11-dev libxext-dev qtbase5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt4-dev qttools5-dev-tools libkf5windowsystem-dev git
```

## Download the latest source

```
mkdir -p ~/repos/tsujan && cd ~/repos/tsujan
git clone https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum.git && cd Kvantum
git checkout master
```

## Compile kvantum

```
cd Kvantum
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

## Install kvantum

```
sudo make install
```

## Get Qt applications to use kvantum

```
echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> ~/.profile
```

After this, **logout** and **log back in**. To apply Kvantum system-wide, and not just for your user, you could add `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum` in `/etc/environment` instead of `~/.profile`.

## To completely uninstall

If you want to uninstall Kvantum installed from source, start by opening a terminal, navigating to the folder where you've extracted (in the build folder from the Kvantum/Kvantum directory if you've followed our instructions) and built the source - e.g. `cd ~/repos/tsujan/Kvantum/Kvantum/build`, and running this command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

You'll also need to remove the `export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum` line from your `~/.profile` file. To do this, open `~/.profile` with a text editor, e.g. kate:

```
kate ~/.profile
```

And remove the `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum` line from this file, then save it, logout and log back in.

*Source: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/use-custom-themes-for-qt-applications.html with some adaptations of my own.*

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:papirus/papirus
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qt5-style-kvantum qt5-style-kvantum-themes
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code to install kvantum manager: `sudo apt install qt5-style-kvantum qt5-style-kvantum-themes`

Comment: This is only available in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. For previous versions, one needs the PPA.