# Need help installing Kvantum Engine on Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, 18.10, lxqt

I'm having trouble trying to actually start the application. I have cloned the repository and compiled it from source using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106837/908936); which is the simplest to follow for linux noobs like me. But after the installation and reboot, I can't see Kvantum anywhere. It's not in the Qt Style options and searching it from the menu gives nothing. What have I done wrong?

Comment: These packages are not available for Ubuntu 18.10, but they are available for [future Ubuntu 19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Kvantum).

Comment: Oh thats a shame. Is there any alternative to let me change the Qt Widget style?

Answer (score 0):

As you have compiled and installed [Kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum/tree/master/Kvantum), then you can:

- use Kvantum Manager [image: km] (`kvantummanager` aka `/usr/local/bin/kvantummanager`):

  [image: Kvantum Manager GUI]
- specify theme for single application like

  ```
  QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum kate
  ```

  or make this permanent

  ```
  echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> ~/.profile
  ```
- follow official [Theme-Config.pdf guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsujan/Kvantum/master/Kvantum/doc/Theme-Config.pdf) to set up the theme.